# Grails fail to receive serialized data

Tags: java, xml, json, grails, model-view-controller

How do I send data (JSON or XML) and deserialize it in grails controller?

I tried `render params` and `render request.JSON` whitch returned me empty json, and also the command approach

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class TestController {

    def test(RestCommand r){
        render r as JSON
    }

}

class RestCommand {
    String data

    static constraints = {
        data nullable: false
    }

}
```

witch resulted in

```
{"data":null,"errors":{"errors":[{"object":"x.x.RestCommand","field":"data","rejected-value":null,"message":"Property [data] of class [class x.x.RestCommand] cannot be null"}]}}
```

here's my curl request:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"id":1}' localhost:8080/myApp/myController/myMethod
```

P.S. I have viewed similar questions in stackexchange, but as I've discussed above, none of the approaches worked.

Comment: your command object holds a string named `data` and you are sending in an `id` as number.  above example works fine, if you `render r as JSON` and send in the proper data (`{"data":"somestring"}`)

Comment: Also `render request.JSON` works fine for `def myMethod()` without `RestCommand`. Could you show more code of your controller?

Comment: @PawełPiecyk Here you go, check my edit. Might the problem has something to do with grails configs?

Comment: @cfrick if you too would check my update, that would be great.

Comment: doesn't the error message make perfect sense?  you say you want a string `data`, that is not allowed to have a `null` value.  then you post json missing `data` and get an error telling you so.

Comment: @cfrick I just understood that I completely misinterpreted the concept of controllers, if I pass object with id, my controller has to have that member... Awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails provides serialized object for you, your data just has to have the same fields as command.

This works for me:

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class TestController {

    def test(RestCommand r){
        if(r.hasErrors()) {
           render (
               status: 400, 
               text: r.getErrors() as JSON)
        } else {
            render "id: "+r.id+" data: "+r.someData
        }
    }

}

class RestCommand {
    Integer id
    String someData

    static constraints = {
        id nullable: false
    } 

}
```

Here's the request:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"id":1,"someData":"here you go some data"}' localhost:8080/myapp/test/test
```

results:

```
id: 1 data: here you go some data
```

Answer (score 0):

They way you are doing it is working (sending JSON to a Controller and deserializing it). If you send JSON to this action, the command will bind the received data (like it does in your example). Your problem is that the data in your curl test is invalid. Normally, you would check if the Command has errors like :

```
def test(RestCommand r){
    if(r.hasErrors()) {
       // handle error
       response.status = 400
       render "error"
       return
    }
    render "ok"
}
```

Comment: The data was not invalid, it was absent. If you'd red the comments and checked the data, you'd see that the answer would be something like "the command does not carry json String, but is deserialized object, so if you're passing id, the command has to have a member called 'id'"